# The border icons disappear when I maximize a Delphi MDIChild window

Tags: delphi, mdichild

I know there is a solution to put a TMainMenu on the MDIForm to decrease the client area. But I have a TActionToolBar for customizable menus and toolbars. Is there a solution to see the border icons of the maximized MDIChilds with this component as well? (4ex overriding some messages or making some api calls)

Comment: The system draws these icons on the main menu bar when a child window is maximized. If you don't provide a main menu bar there is nowhere for them to go. Why don't you draw them yourself on your menu bar?

Comment: I have created some action control as tool bar buttons but its appearence does not change by OS/win appearence settings change. And their position is not locked to the right-top corner.

Comment: The system simply isn't going to do this work for you. You will have to draw them yourself.